# thunar-archive-plugin not working

Tags: compression, thunar, file-roller

After I experienced serious not yet resolved [performance issues with Nautilus](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13913/nautilus-has-become-slow) I decided to move to XUbuntu so I installed its metapackage from Ubuntu and started using it. It turns out that the archive plugin for Thunar (provides the *"Extract here"* option in the contextual menu when right clicking over a compressed archive) is not working, even after I apt-get purged it and reinstalled. It simply doesn't show its options in the contextual menu. What should I do to make it work?

Answer (score 3):

I fixed it by changing corresponding command in the `gnome-file-roller.tap` file. In my case this file has been placed at

```
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/thunar-archive-plugin/gnome-file-roller.tap
```

Just edit it replacing this line:

```
file-roller "--extract-to=$(pwd)" --extract-here --force "$@"
```

with this one:

```
file-roller --extract-here --force "$@"
```

Answer (score 1):

Is

`sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get install xarchiver`

installed?

Comment: I don't see the point here since `thunar-archive-plugin` is supposed to work with `file-roller` as its default compression program. I will try your suggestion anways. Thanks.

Comment: No luck here. I installed xarchiver and it remains the same :-(

Comment: Are you using Xubuntu as a new session or are you using thunar in Ubuntu?

Comment: XUbuntu all the way

Answer (score 1):

Same issue.

Resolved intalling xarchiver and thunar-archive-plugin. I installed both at the same time. xarchiver is not needed now because Thunar-archive-plugin works with file roller, but saids it will work with xarchiver in the future.